# Run function only once for specific time Golang

Tags: go, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need to set a task for specific time with Golang. For example job has ending time so I need to change some rows on table. I searched for it but I could only find periodic tasks with Cron. I don't want to set a cron to check database in every 5 minutes.

**jasonlvhit** has a library named **gocron** for Cron on Golang but I don't think It'll be useful on my problem.

**Solved:**

After @JimB's comment I checked the documentation of the time library and time.AfterFunc function can help me to solve this problem. After func function takes a Duration which must be nanosecond so it'll be useful if you create something like nanoSecondsToSecond()

```
time.AfterFunc(nanoSecondToSecond(10), func() {
    printSometing("Mert")
})
```

If you define a printSomething function you can call it on closure.

```
func printSometing(s string) {
    fmt.Println("Timer " + s)
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a [`time.Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer), or [`time.AfterFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc)?

Comment: I haven't seen the AfterFunc function, sorry. I edited my question with example.

Comment: Just use the duration constants: `10*time.Second`, or if you want a specific time, `t.Sub(time.Now())`.

Comment: @JimB May I ask something? I'm running this code on VPS, if VPS close for some reason, my program will be terminated, so should I set these timers again or will it be executed on the right time?

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this.  I place it in its own go routine so that it is non blocking and addition code can run below it. Often times in conjunction with a server

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Minute)
go func(ticker *time.Ticker) {
  for {
    select {
      case <-ticker.C:
        // do something every 5 minutes as define by the ticker above
      }
    }
}(ticker)
```